# NextJs image component and jsonplaceholder external url

Tags: next.js, jsonplaceholder

In a nextJS project, I want to use jsonplaceholder with /photos route.

When I try to insert image or thumbnails into Image component like bellow, I have an error.

```
import Image from 'next/image'
<Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952" width={150} height={150} />
```

> Server Error
>
> Error: Invalid src prop (https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952) on
> `next/image`, hostname "via.placeholder.com" is not configured under
> images in your `next.config.js` See more info:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

When I check documentation, for external sources, and considering I'm using recent version (13), I should convert my next.config.js like that :

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'via.placeholder.com',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/**',
      },
    ],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

But I still have an error, maybe because of a null port. But I don't know which port via.placeholder.com is using :(

Trying old next version with code bellow doesn't work either:

```
images: {
    domains: ['via.placeholder.com'],
  },
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use curly braces when using a string literal for the image `src`. You can just do something like `<Image src="https://cdn.architect.io/logo/horizontal.png" width={400} height={59.5} alt="Architect Logo" />`. Also if you're loading the image from a server using https, the port should be 443. For more context, I added the following in my `next.config.js` in order to load the image that I referenced:

```js
images: {
  remotePatterns: [
    {
      protocol: 'https',
      hostname: 'cdn.architect.io',
    },
  ],
},
```

Also, when trying to load a .png from `via.placeholder.com`, be sure to include the file type. For example:

```html
<Image src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952.png" width={150} height={150} alt="Placeholder" />
```

Comment: hi, and thank you for your quick answer. For curly braces, my bad, it's just a mistake. The real code is like <Image src={data.thumbnailUrl} width={150} height={150} alt="foo" />. 

The 443 port doesn't work neither

Comment: If I ommit port and path in my remotePattern, I have a different error. He load the alt attribute and my server log : upstream image response failed for https://via.placeholder.com/150/24f355 403 (forbidden)

Comment: I've updated the question with more detail on loading the image

Comment: oh... the url is given without extension... perfectly work with my next.config file and "<Image
          src={data.thumbnailUrl + '.png'}
          width={150}
          height={150}
          alt=""
        />"

Answer (score 0):

Despite the settings mentioned in other answers (I tested new ones `images. remotePatterns` and legacy ones `images.domains`), none was working.

After upgrading from `v13.0.7` to `v13.1.6` it works now :)